# Custom objects vs security rule for enforcing database schema in Firestore

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Since Firestore is a noSQL, it will be schemaless, but I would like to enforce or at least check if the proper data type is being passed in.

**Custom Objects**
According to Firebase,
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data

```
class City {
    constructor ( name, state, country ) {
        this.name = name;
        this.state = state;
        this.country = country;
    }
    toString() {
        return this.name + ', ' + this.state + ', ' + this.country;
    }
}

// Firestore data converter
const cityConverter = {
    toFirestore: (city) => {
        return {
            name: city.name,
            state: city.state,
            country: city.country
            };
    },
    fromFirestore: (snapshot, options) => {
        const data = snapshot.data(options);
        return new City(data.name, data.state, data.country);
    }
};
```

which then they do:

```
const ref = doc(db, "cities", "LA").withConverter(cityConverter);
await setDoc(ref, new City("Los Angeles", "CA", "USA"));
```

I am also using typescript which I can use in the constructor so the developers doesn't miss inputs:
`constructor ( name : String , state : String, country : String )`

**Firebase Rules**
However there is another way, according to this post,
[How can I enforce database schema in Firestore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53819548/how-can-i-enforce-database-schema-in-firestore)
which is to use firebase rule system.

I have only tried the "custom objects" way which works totally fine and this also enforces the developers to catch errors earlier if they are putting in the wrong data types.

Then, is there a particular benefit in using the firebase rule system?

I am doing this as a small project, but in a production setting would the rule system be better since it is more hidden?

Comment: Since security rules are enforced on the backend, they can't be bypassed by user-driven access.  Whether or not that makes it "better" than any other options is purely a matter of opinion.  You should do whatever meets the requirements of your product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your custom objects are a client-side only mechanism.

Custom classes/objects a great way to prevent your own code from making a mistake in how it serializes data to the database. However, they don't protect against malicious actors, who can take the configuration data from your app and use that to write to your database - without using your custom objects.

To protect from such malicious actors you'll need a server-side mechanism, such as Firebase's security rules. Since this executes on the server, not even a malicious actors can bypass it.

Also see: [Is it safe to expose Firebase apiKey to the public?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482366/is-it-safe-to-expose-firebase-apikey-to-the-public)

Comment: To clarify, I assume that they are actually suppose to be used together. Custom classes is for helping developers so that they don't pass wrong information. On the other hand, Firebase's security rules is for protecting against malicious actors (with the added bonus of checking for correct data types).